# Qt slot invokes twice

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, signals-slots

In `mainwindow` there is a slot `MainWindow::establish_connection` in which I'm trying to invoke `Server::establish_connection` in different thread:

```
void MainWindow::establish_connection(const std::string& nickname,
                                      const std::string& ip, int port)
{ 
    auto thread = new QThread(this);
    remote_server = new Server(nickname, ip, port);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), remote_server, SLOT(establish_connection()));

    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connection_established()));

    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(handle_reply()));

    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this,
            SLOT(connection_failed(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(stop_thread()), thread, SLOT(quit()));

    thread->start();
}
```

`Server::establish_connection` method:

```
void Server::establish_connection()
{
    master_socket = std::move(
                std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket>(new QTcpSocket(nullptr)));

    connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(connected()), SIGNAL(connected()));

    connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(readyRead()), SIGNAL(readyRead()));
    connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    master_socket->connectToHost(ip.c_str(), port);
    if (!master_socket->waitForConnected(timeout*1000))
    {
        emit error(master_socket->error());

    }
    emit stop_thread();
}
```

but when `error` signal emits, `MainWindow::connection_failed` invokes twice.

```
void MainWindow::connection_failed(QAbstractSocket::SocketError e)
{
    QString err_msg = remote_server->get_socket()->errorString();

    qDebug() << err_msg;
}
```

Output:

```
"Connection refused"
"Connection refused"
```

How to prevent this issue?

Comment: Maybe specify using Qt::UniqueConnection when you connect your signal slots?  Do you call establish connection multiple times?

Comment: @ChaseHenslee I've made `connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this,
            SLOT(connection_failed(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::UniqueConnection);` but it also invokes twice. Here full code of mainwindow: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e238a18cb85a39c7fca4)

Comment: Isn't it entirely possible that the signal is emitted twice?

Comment: Is it invoked with the same socket error? (I'm guessing so - assuming that's how you get your error string). It sounds like the `error` signal is in fact being emitted multiple times. Per the documentation: "If an error occurs at any stage, `error()` is emitted." and "If the remove host closes the connection, `QAbstractSocket` will emit `error(QAbstractSocket::RemoveHostClosedError)`, during which ..."

Comment: I mean, there are really only  2 possibilities.  Either it's being emitted twice, or it's being registered twice.  Really best way would probably be to add some debug to find out.

Comment: @user3528438 @JamesAdikison @ChaseHenslee Yes, signal emits twice :( Now how should I properly handle this signals that emit consequentially? In my code I show errors in `QMessageBox` and show this twice isn't good idea.

Comment: Why not disconnect the slot once you no longer wish to receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you reemit the signal error from master_socket : `connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));`

This seems to be number one to me.

And here you emit it yourself after timeout:

```
if (!master_socket->waitForConnected(timeout*1000))
{
    emit error(master_socket->error());

}
```

This seems to be your number two.

I think while you wait for the timeout `error()` it is already emitted and relayed by your `connect()`. And afterwards you emit it yourself again. This seems to be super fluent.

Test whether removing this explicit emit does the trick for you.

Alternatively you can put the line `connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));` after your `if` condition to get all errors from that point on. No need to disconnect.

Or put it in the `else` branch because you are only interested in any more errors if a connection could be established:

```
if (!master_socket->waitForConnected(timeout*1000))
{
    emit error(master_socket->error());

} else {

   connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
        SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
}
```

Both should work.

Comment: I cannot remove signal that explicitly emitting because I need to handle timeout error too. I'm just disconnecting signal when catch him.

Comment: Just change the order .. no need to disconnect. Added it to the answer.